# How to import the module to test into the test module

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, directory-structure, cookiecutter

**The problem**

I have a directory structure for my project which follows the standard for Python packages, as it was created with this cookiecutter template: 
https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage#quickstart

The directory structure is

```
project_name
├── project_name
│   ├── __init__.py         
│   └── module1.py
└── tests         
    └── test_module1.py
```

The first code line of `test_module1.py` is:

```
from project_name import module1
```

But I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_name'`.

To my understanding, this should work since the folder called `project_name` is a package, which is ensured by presence of the `__init__.py` file.

I have always had trouble understanding how imports like this work. For my projects I have always just settled with having my tests in the same folder as the modules to test. I know this is bad practice, but the only way I could get the modules to actually import.

**What I already tried**

I have tried renaming the folder with the `__init__.py` file to something else and then import, as I thought it could have something to do with the parent folder and the child folder both having the name `project_name`. This did not work, same error.

I also tried making the test folder into a package by creating an `__init.py__` file inside it, even though the Cookiecutter template does not have that. 
I read in many places that making the test folder into a package is discouraged, but some suggest that structure. That did not work either.

I have searched thoroughly for solutions to this seemingly very standard problem, some of the links are here:

- [Python, importing modules for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636736/python-importing-modules-for-testing)
- https://gist.github.com/tasdikrahman/2bdb3fb31136a3768fac
- [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)
- https://alex.dzyoba.com/blog/python-import/
- [Sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports)
- [Python imports for tests using nose - what is best practice for imports of modules above current package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670275/python-imports-for-tests-using-nose-what-is-best-practice-for-imports-of-modul)

My last try was to start a project with Cookiecutter, so everything would be set up properly form the beginning. However, I still get the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

**What I don't want**

I don't want to modify `sys.path` as many answers seem to suggest. There must be a cleaner way for such a common problem.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit for some additional info (see question from @Nicholas):**

The contents of `__init__.py` is

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Top-level package for project_name."""
__author__ = """my_name"""
__email__ = 'my_email'
__version__ = '0.1.0'
```

Which was generated by the Cookiecutter template.

Inside `test_module1`, I added the following before the before the `ModuleNotFoundError` occurs:

```
import sys
import os

print(sys.path)    
print(os.getcwd())
```

`sys.path` prints a list, where first element is the `tests` directory.

```
['c:\\Users\\...\\project_name\\tests', 
 'C:\\Users\\...\\Miniconda3\\python37.zip', 
 'C:\\Users\\...\\Miniconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\...\\Miniconda3\\lib', 
 'C:\\Users\\...\\Miniconda3', 
 'C:\\Users\\...\\Miniconda3\\lib\\site- packages', 
 'C:\\Users\\...\\Miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 
 'C:\\Users\\...\\Miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 
 'C:\\Users\\...\\Miniconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

I don't know if the lowercase 'c' in the first element matters.

`os.getcwd()` prints the root directory `'c:\Users\....\project_name'`. Also with a lowercase 'c'.

Comment: Are you running the tests from the root `project_name` directory? When you try to run `python -m project_name` from the root folder, it imports the module correctly?

Comment: Yes, I am running ´pytest´ in Anaconda Prompt after having cd'ed into the root ´project_name´ directory. I'm in a virtual conda environment for the project.
But the same thing happens if I try to run the python module itself.

Comment: What's the content of `__init__.py`?
Also, run Python then `import sys;sys.path`. This shows all the paths Python is using to search for imports. In my system it is a lists with an empty string element. That ensures the current folder is used as a search path. You may also want to check what Python see as "current folder" with `import os;os.getcwd()`.

Comment: I edited the question to include these answers at the bottom. Thanks for suggesting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a virtual environment and install the project in order for the test modules to correctly resolve import statements.

In the project root, i.e. the directory `project_name` which contains a subdirectory `project_name` and a subdirectory `tests`, create a `setup.py` (or `pyproject.toml`) file for the package metadata. See [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-setup-py) for details about that part.

From this same project root directory which is now containing the installer (`setup.py`), create and activate a venv and install your project:

```
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activatate  # linux/macOS
# .\Scripts\activate.bat  # windows
pip install --editable .
pip install pytest
pytest
```

If for some reason you don't want to create an installer for your project, you may run pytest like this, from the project directory:

```
python3 -m pytest
```

Unlike the bare `pytest` command, this will add the current working directory to `sys.path` allowing import statements to be resolved in tests.

Comment: `pip install --editable .` did the trick! I'm on windows and had already the `setup.py` from the Cookiecutter template. 
I can now run `pytest` properly from Anaconda Prompt. I still can't run the actual test modules in the editor though, which might also be unimportant. Thanks a lot.